# SFTP connection Failed due to java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch, sshd

I am trying to connect to password less configured server using SFTP.
Sftp connection is successful using terminal.
But when I am connecting in JAVA (using Jsch library) through username and password, I am unable to connect.
My java code:-

```
try {
        try {
            jsch.addIdentity(ftp_Info.getSftpCertFile());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: Add a log message
        }
        session = jsch.getSession(ftp_Info.getUserName(), ftp_Info.getHost(), ftp_Info.getPort());
        String pswd = (password_encypted) // password encryption
        session.setPassword(pswd);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password,hostbased,publickey");
        session.connect(); // exception occurred here
        session.setTimeout(connectionTimeOut);
        Channel channel = session.openChannel(SFTP);
        channel.connect();
        sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);//error logged here
    }
```

I am getting following exception :-

> `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:485)
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:149)`

Please help in troubleshooting or resolving it.
Is there any way except any third party service provider to make my 2048 bit key pass this exception?

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with your crypto suite.  You are probably going to want to switch to use BouncyCastle provider.  What JDK are you using?

Comment: I am using jdk 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under 1.7, I will assume you are utilizing maven for your project.  I would add the bouncycastle dependency to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
    <version>1.45</version>
</dependency>
```

This should work fine with jdk 7.

Then add a line of code to add the BouncyCastle provider as the 1st provider.

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(),1);
```

I would place that prior to your getSftpCertFile() call and prior to any SSL related code.  If you are not using Maven or have a different infrastructure, please let me know.  You could configure the security provider at the JRE level, but I would always prefer to configure at the project level if possible to not impact other projects.

Comment: My key size is 2048 bit, and I think thats the reason I am getting the exception. Will jdk1.8 will make it work or bountyCastleProvider. If jdk1.8 wil work than that will be more feasible.

Comment: The issue with the JCE imposing an artificial restricition on the Diffie-Hellman primes (JDK-651495) should have been in addressed in JDK8u56.  So as long as you use a JDK8u56 or later this should address the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help @M.Rizzo